# Returning Guid of newly created item in Sharepoint Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am using the method

```
File.SaveBinaryDirect
```

in *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client* to insert new documents in a Sharepoint Library. just wondering what is the most effective way of getting the Guids of those new records.

Comment: BTW ListItem IDs are always integers in SharePoint

Comment: All items in Sharepoint have a GUID too

Comment: Ahh ok, you're talkin the UniqueId property on serverside om?! That's not exisiting on the CSOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've just saved the file to a particular URL - get the File by that URL, and then use the ListItemAllFields property to get the ListItem that would contain those IDs

From [here](http://treenovum-wss.com/alavpa/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=113):

```
var FileSrvRelUrl = "/sub/doclib/Folder/File.doc";
using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[100]))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, FileSrvRelUrl, fileStream, false);
}
var web = clientContext.Web;
var f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(FileSrvRelUrl);
var item = f.ListItemAllFields;
item["SomeField"] = "Value";

item.Update();
clientContext.Load(item, i=>i.Id);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```